# Subtract Quantity From Previous Row MySQL

Tags: mysql

Having a tough time with this. I'm echo'ing this data out in PHP but I figured it would be better to make a query in MySQL.

Here's my table:

[image]

My Query (wrong):

```
SELECT i1.Quantity,
i1.timestamp,
(i2.Quantity - i1.Quantity) as sold_qty 
FROM InventoryTest_history i1
INNER JOIN
InventoryTest_history i2 ON i2.id = i1.id + 1
WHERE i1.SKU = '(L) U-Joint'
```

Is only retrieving two rows, and the sold_qty is wrong.

[image]

The result I am trying to achieve would look like this:

```
Quantity |  timestamp   | sold_qty
985         2016-12-27      0  
960         2016-12-28      25
955         2016-12-29      5
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this without JOIN the table: the out SELECT is only to hide some columns.

```
SELECT Quantity, `timestamp`, sold_qty
FROM (
    SELECT i.*,
    @sold_qty := GREATEST(@last_qty - i.`Quantity`,0) as sold_qty,
    @last_qty := i.`Quantity` as last_qty
    FROM InventoryTest_history i
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @last_qty := '', @sold_qty := 0) as init
    ORDER BY `timestamp`
    ) as result;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * from InventoryTest_history;

+----+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| id | SKU         | Quantity | timestamp           |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | (L) U-Joint |      985 | 2016-12-27 10:08:58 |
|  2 | (L) U-Joint |      960 | 2016-12-28 10:09:52 |
|  3 | (L) U-Joint |      955 | 2016-12-29 16:01:02 |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0,02 sec)

mysql> SELECT Quantity, `timestamp`, sold_qty
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT i.*,
    ->     @sold_qty := GREATEST(@last_qty - i.`Quantity`,0) as sold_qty,
    ->     @last_qty := i.`Quantity` as last_qty
    ->     FROM InventoryTest_history i
    ->     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @last_qty := '', @sold_qty := 0) as init
    ->     ORDER BY `timestamp`
    ->     ) as result;
+----------+---------------------+----------+
| Quantity | timestamp           | sold_qty |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
|      985 | 2016-12-27 10:08:58 |        0 |
|      960 | 2016-12-28 10:09:52 |       25 |
|      955 | 2016-12-29 16:01:02 |        5 |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT i.*,
    -> @sold_qty := GREATEST(@last_qty - i.`Quantity`,0) as sold_qty,
    -> @last_qty := i.`Quantity` as last_qty
    -> FROM InventoryTest_history i
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @last_qty := '', @sold_qty := 0) as init
    -> ORDER BY `timestamp`;
+----+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
| id | SKU         | Quantity | timestamp           | sold_qty | last_qty |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | (L) U-Joint |      985 | 2016-12-27 10:08:58 |        0 |      985 |
|  2 | (L) U-Joint |      960 | 2016-12-28 10:09:52 |       25 |      960 |
|  3 | (L) U-Joint |      955 | 2016-12-29 16:01:02 |        5 |      955 |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: really appreciate the code. I'm in the process of working my way through each piece so I can fully understand it. Doing some testing on my table I believe there is going to be an issue with the `GREATEST()` function.  Here's what I mean: https://s27.postimg.org/46h2hwstf/image.png `sold_qty` for the last row needs to be `-7` to reflect new incoming stock and returns. Was wondering your thoughts on modifying this to support negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be use a correlated subquery. This certainly isn't the most efficient approach for large sets, but for a limited number of rows being returned, it's workable.

There appears to be a sequence you want the rows processed and returned, but there is no `ORDER BY` clause. From the example data, it looks like it's either ascending by `timestamp` column, descending by `Quantity` column, and/or ascending by `id`. We're just guessing.

Assuming the sequence is by `timestamp` and `id`, and assuming that the `(timestamp,id)` tuple is unique...  those are fairly reasonable assumptions, but they are just assumptions, and pretty big ones...

```
SELECT ih.Quantity
     , ih.timestamp

     , IFNULL(
                 ( SELECT pr.Quantity
                     FROM InventoryTest_history pr
                    WHERE pr.SKU = ih.SKU
                      AND pr.timestamp <= ih.timestamp
                      AND (pr.timestamp < ih.timestamp OR pr.id < ih.id )
                    ORDER BY pr.SKU DESC, pr.timestamp DESC, pr.id DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                 )
                 - ih.Quantity
       ,0) AS sold_qty

  FROM InventoryTest_history ih
 WHERE ih.SKU = '(L) U-Joint'
 ORDER BY ...
```

---

For the best shot at adequate performance, we would want a covering index available for the correlated subquery, as an example of a suitable index:

```
 ... ON InventoryTest_history (SKU, timestamp, id, quantity)
```

If the rows should be considered sequenced in an order other than by `(timestamp,id)`, the `ORDER BY` and the conditions in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery need to be modified.

---

This is just one possible approach. There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

Comment: Your assumptions were right, thanks for the info! Interesting approach. Only issue is its returning negative values, `0` `-25` `-5` but works well otherwise :)

Comment: @bbruman:  Doh! My bad. The negative values are because the expression is doing the subtraction backwards... doing `b-a` instead of `a-b`...  i've edited the answer to fix that.