# MySQL Self-Join Clause (Incrementing ID)

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have a table called "stocks", and its records are described in the following

```
ID| Date       | Qty
1 | 2017-01-03 | 10
2 | 2017-02-11 | 15
3 | 2017-03-15 | 16
4 | 2017-04-25 | 30
5 | 2017-06-20 | 40
```

I want to find the difference between the "Qty" of each successive rows. For that purpose, I use the query:

```
SELECT first_table.id as "First Table ID"
     , first_table.date AS "From"
     , first_table.qty AS "First Table Qty"
     , second_table.id as "Second Table ID"
     , second_table.date AS "To"
     , second_table.qty AS "Second Table Qty"
     , (second_table.qty - first_table.qty) AS Quantity_Difference 
  FROM stocks first_table 
  JOIN stocks second_table 
    ON first_table.id + 1 = second_table.id
```

The following  depicts the result that I got from the above query.

[image: link]

My questions are:

1) In the above query, what does the clause `first_table.id + 1 = second_table.id` mean?

2) In the JOIN clause, I add "1" on the first_table ID (i.e. first_table.id + 1). 
But, in the result that I got, why does the second_table ID that get incremented? I thought that, by adding 1 to the first_table ID, the first_table ID that should be incremented instead of the second table ID.

Comment: `first_table.id + 1 = second_table.id` asks for the second_table record whose id is one more than the first_table record's.

Comment: Joining an id incrementally this way is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Tell the person who wrote that query that an AUTO_INCREMENT column is not guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: Hi Glorian implement your first table as code and not as an image. Its tiny so .. take the time to rid the downvotes.

Comment: @Strawberry I joined the ID because this is just for the sake of asking this question :)

Comment: And my comment is just for the sake of answering it

Comment: @Glorian Strawberry's comment is based on the problem that Paul Spiegel points out. Your query will skip rows whenever there's a gap in the ID sequence.

Comment: @Barmar : Yes. I completely aware of that problem before asking this question. Again, this query is just for the sake of asking the meaning behind "first_table.id + 1 = second_table.id". I just did not find a better example for representing my question. Thanks for the heads up anyway!

Comment: @ZF007 : Done! thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @ Glorian.. that action is worth my upvote... btw.. don't forget to finish the tour for nice rep and rewards. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @ZF007: Thanks. Apologize. This is my first time asking a question at SO.

Comment: no problem... we've all been there once... that's why firs questions are reviewed by more experienced users before posting the quesion is done ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above query, what does the clause `first_table.id + 1 = second_table.id` mean?

It means to join rows in the table whose IDs differ by `1`.

> But, in the result that I got, why does the second_table ID that get incremented?

It's not incrementing IDs, it's adding 1 to the ID of one row and comparing that with the ID of another row. When `first_table.id = 2`, `first_table.id + 1` is `3`, so it joins that row with `second_table.id = 3`.

The addition is only done in the `WHERE` clause, you're not returning the result in the `SELECT` list. So it selects the original `first_table.id`, not `first_table.id + 1`.

As mentioned in the comments, this query will only work properly when IDs all increment by `1`. If there are any gaps in the ID sequence, you'll skip the `first_table.id` before the gap and `second_table.id` after the gap. See [Subtract Quantity From Previous Row MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384289/subtract-quantity-from-previous-row-mysql) for a better way to subtract values from adjacent rows that doesn't depend on IDs being sequential.